# Throwing a descriptive error

Tags: c#

I have a UtilityMethod that returns a string based on a lookup.

```
public static string UtilityMethod(int id)
{
    var result = MyListOfThings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ThingId == id);

    if (result == null)
    {
        // throw error here
    }
    return result.ThingName;
}
```

My question is, is it correct to throw an error here? And how should I throw the error.  The error should be descriptive so it indicates exactly what should be done in order to fix.

Comment: We have absolutely no idea because this all depends on the semantics of your method. Is it correct to return `null`? Who knows! Also, note that your code can already throw NRE if no thing with that id is found.

Comment: Probably its pseudo code anyway

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean throw an exception?

Normally you should not throw an exception if the outcome of your program is what can be predicted or occur often.

Instead use an error code (0 for success, 1,2,3 for different types of errors)

Comment: I guess this is an error message for devs not users. Users would receive a generic err msg. Devs would get emailed the error. Error would happen as a result of bad config

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a library method that can throw exceptions, or more specifically, writing a library that throughout its code base throw the same exception (e.g. `Exception` or `LibraryException`) for different situations, you may want to include an error number in your exceptions:

```
public class LibraryException : Exception
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public LibraryException(int errorCode, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

This way your GUI code can catch this exception, and translate the error number to a user-friendly (localized) error message - without having to do the localization nor the user-friendliness in the library.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, is *not* finding a matching item in the repository really *exceptional*?  Meaning, should it be *expected* that an item is found, or does it represent an *error* in the program or a violation of an assumption?  If it's not exceptional, then returning `null` would mean "There's not an object that matches your criteria", and the caller can then decide what to do from there.

Throwing an exception would allow you to include a message, but you have no other information other than an item was not found, so it would not provide any information that the caller doesn't already know, and would add the overhead of creating and throwing an exception that the caller then has to handle.

> The error should be descriptive so it indicates exactly what should be done in order to fix

What is there to fix?  You look for an item with the given `id`, and if none is found you return `null`.  I don't see any benefit of throwing an exception other than a more friendly error, but you can document the behavior so that it's apparent to the caller what a `null` return value means.

Answer (score 0):

What situation are you trying to deal with? Can your list be empty? Can the alias be null?

Your error will be thrown if the list is not empty and if the `Thing` object with matching id has a null `ThingAlias`.

If your list is empty, `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` and you will get a `NullReferenceException` on the first line of your method.

Depending on your application, you could do some of the following:

- return null if the list is empty and handle null in the calling method,
- return a special message if the list is empty, e.g. "<no items in list>" [if it's going to be displayed without further processing],
- throw an exception if the list is empty [good idea if the list should never be empty],
- use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of FirstOrDefault to specify a default `Thing` object if the list is empty, e.g. `MyListOfThings.DefaultIfEmpty(new Thing(default_params).First(t => t.ThingId == id)`,
- use a dictionary instead of a list to ensure that you have at most one item with a given id, then you can use [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the case where the item isn't found.